# Format Code for Currency Microsoft Chart SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, bids

Working on an SSRS in BIDS 2005 and I'm creating a chart that shows money values, in USD. How can I format using the Format code?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `[Currency]` as the format code, you should have the data displayed with the currency sign of the current locale (which is USD, assuming the user runs this on a computer with US locale).

Thea above did not work. The solution - according to the comment - was to use `$#.00` as the format string.

Comment: Yes i understand that but what do I type in the format code box to provide me with the $00.00? Typing just [Currency] in the field overrides the value and only shows the word [Currency].

Comment: Do you mean it shows the word [Currency] in the chart instead of the formatted value?

Comment: You might want to use $#,##0.00 so you get commas and a leading zero when neceesary, or try my answer

Answer (score 2):

Normally the report server uses the format that it has for its regional settings but you can change this to use the user's regional settings.

On the report properties, in the Language property set it to:

```
=User!Language
```

Then use the international formatting codes throughout your report. In your example, `C2` will give you the appropriate currency format (usually with a leading dollar sign, commas, and two decimal places) in the way the user expects to see it. Other examples are:

N0    Number with commas and no decimal places

P1    Percentage with one decimal place

d     Short date format